# How to implode a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I have an array of arrays like:

```
$array = [["1.","COTV_LITE(1800)"],["2.","COTV_PREMIUM(2200)"]]
```

Now, I want to implode this array such that it would return something like this:

1. COTV_LITE(1800)
2. COTV_PREMIUM(2200)

How do I achieve this? Calling just the `implode()` function did not work:

```
implode ('<br>', $array);
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php or https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Answer (score 4):

You can call [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to implode the nested arrays:

```
echo implode('<br>', array_map(function($a) { return implode(' ', $a); }, $array));
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/5PIl9z)

output:

```
1. COTV_LITE(1800)<br>2. COTV_PREMIUM(2200)
```

Comment: This is the reason - 1. COTV_LITE(1800)<br>2. COTV_PREMIUM(2200). It does not break into a new line.

Comment: Why doesn't it break into a new line? That's what `<br>` does in HTML.

Comment: I mean <br> ought to break the arrays into newline. The <br> ought not to show.

Answer (score 1):

You can use variable length arguments `variadic` in PHP >= 5.6

**Option1**

```
$items = [["1.","COTV_LITE(1800)"],["2.","COTV_PREMIUM(2200)"]];
echo implode(' ',array_merge(...$items));
```

Output

```
1. COTV_LITE(1800) 2. COTV_PREMIUM(2200)
```

This is more of a `precursor` for the next option.

**Option2**

If you want to get a bit more creative you can use `preg_replace` too:

```
$items = [["1.","COTV_LITE(1800)"],["2.","COTV_PREMIUM(2200)"]];
$replace = [
    '/^(\d+\.)$/' => '<li>\1 ',
    '/^(\w+\(\d+\))$/' => '\1</li>'
];

echo '<ul>'.implode(preg_replace(array_keys($replace),$replace,array_merge(...$items))).'</ul>';
```

Output

```
<ul><li>1. COTV_LITE(1800)</li><li>2. COTV_PREMIUM(2200)</li></ul>
```

**Option3**

And lastly using an `ol`ordered list, which does the numbers for you.  In this case we only need the second item from the array (index 1):

```
$items = [["1.","COTV_LITE(1800)"],["2.","COTV_PREMIUM(2200)"]];

echo '<ol><li>'.implode('</li><li>',array_column($items,1)).'</li></ol>';
```

Output

```
<ol><li>COTV_LITE(1800)</li><li>COTV_PREMIUM(2200)</li></ol>
```

Personally, I would put it in the `ol` that way you don't have to worry about the order of the numbers, you can let HTML + CSS handle them.  Also it's probably the easiest and most semantically correct way, But I don't know if the numbering in the array has any special meaning or not.

In any case I would most definitely put this into a list to render it to HTML. This will give you a lot more options for styling it, later.

**Update**

> want to use option 1. But how do I put each option on a different line using `<br>`

That one will put the `<br>` between each array element:

```
   echo implode('<br>',array_merge(...$items));
```

Output

```
  1.<br>COTV_LITE(1800)<br>2.<br>COTV_PREMIUM(2200)
```

The only way to easily fix that (while keeping the [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)) is with [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), which is the second one.  So I will call this:

**Option 1.2**

```
$items = [["1.","COTV_LITE(1800)"],["2.","COTV_PREMIUM(2200)"]];

echo implode(preg_replace('/^(\w+\(\d+\))$/',' \1<br>',array_merge(...$items)));
```

Output

```
1. COTV_LITE(1800)<br>2. COTV_PREMIUM(2200)<br>
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e3f206728d9556afa038f67e6b4b25a2ec86ddfe)

Basically there is no way to tell where the end item is after merging them. That operation effectively flattens the array out and gives us something like this:

```
 ["1.","COTV_LITE(1800)","2.","COTV_PREMIUM(2200)"]
```

So that Regex does this `'COTV_PREMIUM(2200)'` becomes `' COTV_PREMIUM(2200)<br>'`. This is just a way of changing that without having to dip into the array with some logic or something.  WE wind up with this modification to the array:

```
["1."," COTV_LITE(1800)<br>","2."," COTV_PREMIUM(2200)<br>"]
```

Then with [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) we just flatten it again into a string:

```
 "1. COTV_LITE(1800)<br>2. COTV_PREMIUM(2200)<br>"
```

The Regex `^(\w+\(\d+\))$`

- `^` - Match start of string
- `(...)` - capture group 1

  - `\w+` - match any working character `a-zA-Z0-9_` one or more, eg. `COTV_PREMIUM`
  - `\(` - match the `(` literally
  - `\d+` - match digits `0-9` one or more, eg `2200`
  - `\)` - match the `)` literally
- `$` - match end of string

So this matches the pattern of the second (or even) items in the array, then we replace that with this:

The Replacement `' \1<br>'`

- `{space}` - adds a leading space
- `\1` - the value of capture group 1  (from above)
- `<br>` - append a line break

Hope that makes sense.  This should work as long as they meet that pattern. Obviously we can adjust the pattern, but with such a small sample size it's hard for me to know what variations will be there.

For example something as simple as `(.+\))$` will work [TestIt](https://regex101.com/r/KOQB5H/2). This one just looks for the ending `)`.  We just need somethng to capture all of the even ones, while not matching the odd.  Regular expressions can be very confusing the first few times you see them, but they are extremely powerful.

**PS** - I added a few links to the function names, these go the the PHP documentation page for them.

Cheers!

Comment: I want to use option 1. But how do I put each option on a different line using <br>

Comment: You can put `<br>` in place of the `' '`, but  this will put a `br` in between all array elements.  Not just between the nested one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$items = [["1.","COTV_LITE(1800)"],["2.","COTV_PREMIUM(2200)"]];
$imploded = [];
foreach($items as $item) {
    $item_entry = implode(' ', $item);
    echo $item_entry . '<br/>'; // display items
    $imploded[] = $item_entry;
}
// your desired result is in $imploded variable for further use
```

Comment: `$imploded[] = ...`

Comment: Then `implode` after the loop.

Comment: `print_r()` is not appropriate for user output, just for debugging.

Comment: yes, left it there for debugging on purpose, it can be removed at will